# NSTextField Overwrite Mode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

Is there a way to create a NSTextField where the input of the user replaces the text under the cursor?

And in addition: is there a way to change the cursor to a block cursor?

Comment: What do you mean by text under the cursor? You want to add a bunch of text that follows the cursor?

Comment: I mean the character under the cursor. Just a bit like the replace mode of vim ([vim like a pro](http://vimlikeapro.blogspot.co.at/p/insert-overwrite-change.html))

Comment: the cursor is a bar that goes between chars... if you want to emulate insert vs overwrite, like old timey Word Perfect you will have to use the controls delegate methods... or make a custom subclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first problem, get the selected range of the text view, then replace that text with the input. So something like

```
NSRange range = [textView selectedRange];
[textView.textStorage replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:input];
```

For your second problem, refer to [this](http://programming.jugglershu.net/wp/?p=765).